# Разновидности перечислений в программе TMP - факториал

Tags: c++, c++11, метапрограммирование, шаблоны-с++

Вот пример кода, в котором используются перечисления с областью видимости:

```
#include <iostream>

using value_t = std::uint64_t;

template <unsigned n>
struct Factorial
{
    enum class Result : value_t
    { value = n * static_cast< value_t >(Factorial< n-1 >::Result::value) };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0>
{
    enum class Result : value_t 
    { value = 1 };
};

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 5;

    value_t result = static_cast< value_t >(Factorial<N>::Result::value);

    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что перечисления с областью видимости в целом не предназначены для преобразований их значений посредством `static_cast`? И корректно ли будет в данной ситуации использовать перечисления без области видимости, которые позволяют неявные преобразования, т.е. убрать `class` и `static_cast` из кода выше так:

```
#include <iostream>

using value_t = std::uint64_t;

template <unsigned n>
struct Factorial
{
    enum  Result : value_t
    { value = n * (Factorial< n-1 >::value) };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0>
{
    enum Result : value_t 
    { value = 1 };
};

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 5;

    value_t result = (Factorial<N>::value);

    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Еще есть и третий вариант - с использованием не именованного перечисления. Но он получается из второго примера кода посредством удаления имени `Result`. В чем будет отличие такого варианта от второго? Будет ли какое-то существенное отличие?

```
#include <iostream>

using value_t = std::uint64_t;

template <unsigned n>
struct Factorial
{
    enum : value_t
    { value = n * Factorial< n-1 >::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0>
{
    enum : value_t 
    { value = 1 };
};

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 5;

    value_t result = Factorial<N>::value;

    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Т.е. константу времени компиляции нам предоставляют все три типа перечислений, но что будет являться наиболее правильным выбором в рамках данной задачи?

Comment: а зачем вы вообще это на enum делаете? Почему бы просто не использовать `static value_t value = ... `

Comment: @pavel только `static const value_t value` лучше для внутриклассовой инициализации... Ну да не важно. Интересует именно про `enum`. Я понимаю, что новый стандарт вводит "scoped" перечисления, чтобы не засорять пр-ва имен, но дозволительно ли его использование в такой задаче по сравнению с двумя другими вариантами?

Comment: `enum` тут, конечно, даром не нужен. Но вряд ли можно сказать, что "перечисления с областью видимости в целом не предназначены для преобразований их значений посредством `static_cast`". Тут ситуация несколько иная: обычные перечисления не позволяют контролировать эти процессы, а `scoped` вариант — позволяет. Т.е. для них можно писать специальные функции и операторы, которые будут работать только с конкретным(-и) перечислением(-ями). В том числе и функцию перобразования во что-то, написанную поверх `static_cast`. И все будет под контролем.